# Paris - Saturday 22nd January - recording a Maybach

Tags: location-recording

OK, I am calling out for anyone in the area of Paris, France. I do not have the necessary gear to record a car however if anyone of you does, well maybe you could come 'round and help yourself.

I was told today that on Saturday I'll be recording dialogue for a scene for which a Maybach is being rented for 8 hours. I asked the director about whether we need the car's sounds for this scene, and he said "it's ok, we'll add it in post"... Now, WHERE are you going to find Maybach cars' recordings, M. Director?!

I don't know about the location, whether it'll be noisy, reverberant or ideal... if someone is even remotely interested please be sure to give me a shout, that's what the first S in SSD is for :)

I'd be happy to help with the recording, would you care to share the material so I can use it?

Answer (score 1):

Hey Justin,

I'm in Paris but don't have my kit with me at the moment (still not fully installed in the city yet). However, if you need a hand I'd love to 'come round' and help out.

Gimme an email and let me know - colinhuntersound[at]gmail[dot]com

Comment: I love Social Sound Design. It puts the Social in Sound Design. :-)

Comment: Definitely! Whilst we're on the subject, if anyone is ever passing through Paris gimme a yell and we can hook up. 